# TYPO3 10.4.x: Typoscript to get actual languageUid

Tags: typoscript, typo3-10.x

how do I replace the following typoscript working in TYPO3 9.5 to work in TYPOP3 10.4. I don't want to use conditions. I need to get the UID of the actual language.

```
lib.lid= TEXT
lib.lid.data = TSFE:sys_language_uid
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it. Maybe it helps s.o.else:

```
lib.lid= TEXT
lib.lid.data = sitelanguage:languageId
```